# Imparting a number's sign onto another number?

Tags: c#, math

I am looking for a concise way to take the sign (positivity or negativity) of a number, and impart it onto another number.

## For example:

We are given two numbers, the first is the integer 1, the second is unknown until execution time.
If the unknown number is less than 0, our number becomes -1.
If the unknown number is greater-than or equals to 0, our number becomes 1.

#### If our unknown number is X:

[image]

#### As code:

```
int before = AnyNonzeroInt(); //for this example we will choose 1.
int X = rand(Int32.Min, Int32.Max);
int after = ...
```

I am personally using C# 4.5, however I believe a good solution would be fairly language agnostic.

I can think of several ways of doing this, but all involve if-else-case statements or ternary operators. I would like a mathematical way of doing it.

#### EDITS:

I do not have an aversion to ternary operators. However, the codebase that I am working on has a set of code guidelines, ternary operators are not allowed, as they are seen to make code more complex(I know I know.. I did not make this rule).

I do however, believe that I will take this question, and its answers to the next team meeting, that way I can show how necessary I believe ternary operators are.

Comment: I don't understand your aversion to ternaries.  An expression like `(X < 0) ? -1 : 1` will compile into almost no code (assembly languages eat comparisons like that (and setting things to 1 or -1) for breakfast.  Doing floating point math obscures your intent and will be much slower

Comment: What if the unknown number becomes zero?

Comment: @RufusL, under the rules, after will be `1`.

Comment: It seems mathematically inconsistent to force the sign of zero to be positive, but I understand that you want the magnitude of the result to be set regardless of the input. You are forcing a special case (when `X=0`) but what to avoid using a branch statement for such cases.  BTW Fortran has a two-argument `sign(x,y)` that does exactly that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var after = X / Math.Abs(X);
```

Dividing a number by itself gives 1, doing it by the absolute value ensures the sign does not change. Note that the 0 case is not handled here (don't want to divide by 0!). Probably need an if statement or ternary for that.

OP notes that his set has no numbers between 0 and -0.01, so adding a small number like 0.00001 to X before the division could solve the 0 issue.

Also, as other answers/comments have mentioned, the aversion to a ternary here is odd. A simple branch assignment is way cheaper than addition and division.

Comment: Great! Thank you, I had not thought of this!

Comment: If we are looking for purely a mathematical way of doing this(which I am). I believe you could handle 0, by adding a very small float to X beforehand. such as `X += .000001F`

Comment: My calculations only require getting the sign, and they do not need to be more than a hundredth accurate, since the data I'm dealing with is in hundredths.

Comment: @Dylan What happens when X is -.0000001F? :)

Comment: Thats what I was saying though, my data comes in increments of .01, so I would have either 0 or -.01. Your worry would exist with a different data set.

Comment: @Dylan Ah, then sure. Adding  a small increment like that would be fine

Comment: `Math.Abs` also uses an `if` statement, though... :D

Comment: Make sure you have a try catch, for the case where `X == (-1 * yourEpsilon)`.  @Dylan, so your code above (with the `rand` function) isn't actually what you have, you have data coming from a data source.  I hope there isn't any noise in that source (or, you have a try/catch)

Comment: @Flydog57 Apparently X cannot be the epsilon here. Rufus... that's probably true, but at least its a real math operator :D

Answer (score 5):

```
var after = (X < 0) ? -1 : 1;
```

That's cheaper than a division, it's also clearer as to your intentions

Comment: I like this as well, it also handles X being 0. Although for my case, it should be gte 0.

Comment: If ternary's are allowed, I would go with this. The OP specifically asked for a math function though

Comment: @Dylan >= is the opposite of <, he's already got it matching your question output

Comment: That could easily be a function (or a `Func<double, int>`)

Answer (score 2):

Why not:

```
var after = Math.Sign(x)*before;
```

Comment: Returns 0 with a 0 input: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.sign?view=netframework-4.7.2. Also; cheating ;)

Comment: `Math.Sign` uses `if` statements. :)